# Process id 'x' is not an active process ID

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to restore trans log files into  database DBrestore which is in standby mode for every 1 hour . So I created a job where it kills all the process first and then restores the  log files into the database,  but sometimes the job  fails giving the error as : Process id '71' Is not an active process ID, the process id changes every time  it fails. 
Im using this query to kill the process

```
declare @sql as varchar(20), @spid as int
select @spid = min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  
 where dbid = db_id('DBrestore') 
 and spid != @@spid    

while (@spid is not null)
begin
print 'Killing process ' + cast(@spid as varchar) + ' ...'
set @sql = 'kill ' + cast(@spid as varchar)
exec (@sql)

select 
    @spid = min(spid)  
from 
    master..sysprocesses  
where 
    dbid = db_id('DBrestore') 
    and spid != @@spid
end
```

What changes do I need to make in this query to make sure it only takes the process id which is in active.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation provided in the link below, it mentions that 'active' processes are captured via status.  If you add that to the where condition it should limit your query to active processes.

```
declare @sql as varchar(20), @spid as int
select @spid = min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  
 where dbid = db_id('DBrestore') 
 and spid != @@spid    

while (@spid is not null)
begin
print 'Killing process ' + cast(@spid as varchar) + ' ...'
set @sql = 'kill ' + cast(@spid as varchar)
exec (@sql)

select 
    @spid = min(spid)  
from 
    master..sysprocesses  
where 
    dbid = db_id('DBrestore') 
    and spid != @@spid
    and status = 'running'
end
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, cause your comment was useless .. answer is pretty correct and valid. Though it lacks explanation but it successfully points to a right resource or documentation which itself is enough.

Comment: @EricHartman thanks for your reply.  I will try again using status in my query